# Break build on Travis if pylint doesn't have an specific rate

Tags: travis-ci, pylint, pylintrc

I currently have a project that I'm using `pylint` and `pytest`. I use Travis to validate my build, and also run `pylint` to verify the code quality.

But I wanted to do something different and not finding anywhere about how I should proceed. I want my Travis build to break if the code rating is below `9.5`, not even running the `pytest` script. Therefore I can guarantee that all the guidelines are being followed.

What can I do to trigger this? Do I have to configure my `.travis.yml` or `pylintrc`?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to go about this:

- write your own reporter for pylint that exits with something non-zero when the report score is below the threshold. [custom reporter](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_guide/features.html#reports-options)
- hook into/extend the pytest-pylint plugin. Which already has programmatic access to the linter run. [pylint-pytest code](https://github.com/carsongee/pytest-pylint/blob/master/pytest_pylint.py#L150) (runs before the actual pytest tests)